# New Mac User needs help installing Picasa and then importing all i photos into picasa with correct titles

Tags: photos.app, picasa

Have i photo with pictures in named folders. Want to install Picasa. When I did this picasa imported all the iphotos with goofy names, not like the iphoto names. would like to install picassa then put the iphotos into picasa the same as it looks in i photo. BTW, i am a new mac user, and recently copied all my photos from picasa to i photo. now i want to put picassa back on new mac. I prpbably should have installed picassa first on to the mac and put the photos from thePC to picassa on the mac. Now iam stuck. So, how to put picassa on mac and then put all (4,000 pictures in named files)from the iphot back into picassa for mac. Help

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the photos from Picassa
2. Export the photos from iPhoto to a folder named by titles (or as you like)
3. Import from the filesystem to Picasa